# regular expression form to match string

Tags: ios, regex, nsregularexpression

I am using IOS regular expression engine to match any text in the form:

```
"[h1]test text[/h1]"
```

i wrote: `@"\\[h1]([^.]*)[/h1\\]]"`

to match this form, but it is working sometimes and other times it matches text out of bound of the last bracket, is it the best form to match these strings or what you suggest ?

Comment: `([^.]*?)` in the middle instead, otherwise it will take the longest possible match, even if it could stop sooner.

Comment: thank you, it matched to the last slash only, i changed regular expression to : @"\\[h1]([^.]*?)[/h1]]", then it worked, i don't know why!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using `(.*?)` instead of `([^.]*?)`.

It looks want you want is "between `[h1]` and `[/h1]` match anything." That would be `(.*?)`.
What you have is "between `[h1]` and `[/h1]` match anything which is not a period (`.`)."

In addition, you have a problem with your ending `[/h1\\]]` means end with a `/`, `h`, `1`, or `]`. I think you want `\\[/h1]` which means end with the string `[/h1]`.

The final regex would be `@"\\[h1](.*?)\\[/h1]"`.